# How to set up PIC16F877A on breadboard

Tags: pic

I have to do a project in embedded systems. I will be using PIC16F877A micro controller. I have worked before on pic development board. On the development board all the components are already connected. SO basically i have done the programming part only. Now i have to make the circuit on the breadboard. I have no idea which all components to connect to the PIC. I have goggled "How to set up PIC" and found nothing  useful. Are there any tutorials that i can follow.

Comment: When you Google for "16f877a circuit", you get loads of examples of how to set up the oscillator crystal and power etcetera.

Comment: "How to set up PIC" isn't a very good search phrase, by the way. Absolutely no offense intended, but you may want to check out http://www.google.com/insidesearch/searcheducation/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V<sub>DD</sub> connects to your positive voltage supply. V<sub>SS</sub> connects to ground. §14.2 of [the PIC16F87XA datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39582C.pdf) shows you how to connect an external oscillator or crystal if required. §14.4 shows how to connect MCLR* if required. Connect the other pins as appropriate for the programmed code.

Comment: Don't forget to feed the PIC with a nice, smooth, and regulated power supply. It's often good to include a small capacitor across Vss and GND as well.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to do more research before asking a question. Every thing you need to know about the micro controller is in the data sheet. I don't think you will be able to use the pic if you don't go through the data sheet and understand it. Having said that, below is a PIC16F877A set up to drive a led.

http://bilalahmedbhatti.wordpress.com/simple-pic-projects/basic-pic16f877a-circuitry/